# using odeint & odeintw for complex equations when initial conditions are real

Tags: python, odeint

`scipy.integrate.odeint` does not handle complex values.  Warren Weckesser has created a wrapper [odeintw](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw) which converts a complex system into real systems.

In line 176 of _odeintw.py, it checks to see whether there really are complex numbers, by checking if the initial condition is complex.  But there are other ways that the equations might end up being complex.

This has caused some bugs for me, and so I have changed line 176 to simply be `if False:` so that it uses the complex version.

So - is this a bug or a feature?  In other words, am I potentially breaking something by doing this?

Here is some sample code:

```
from odeintw import odeintw
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Solve \dot{y} = cy$ with $y(0)=1$ and c=\sqrt(-1)

def dy_dt(Y, t, c):
    y_val = Y[0]
    return [y_val*c]

y0 = [1]
c=1j

times = numpy.linspace(0,10,21)
y = odeintw(dy_dt, y0, times, args = (c,))

plt.plot(numpy.real(y), numpy.imag(y))
plt.savefig('odeintw_error.pdf')
```

This fails for `odeintw`, but works with the change I have suggested.

Comment: This is explained in the docstring of `odeintw`: "If the solution is to be complex, the initial condition must be complex."

Comment: Does it break anything if I remove that test?  or is it simply a loss of speed in the cases that are real?

Comment: I don't think it will break anything.  It will waste time and memory if the system is actually real.  Why not just use `y0 = [1 + 0j]`?

Comment: I don't suppose you have a citable reference for the repository?  [e.g., https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/]